# ClassCastException when casting an Object to List<String>

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I'm developing and Android application and I have implemented a class for all handling with the shared preferences. This class holds a universal method for getting preferences, it's universal in that way it returns different kind of datatype depending on it's in parameters. The types of data I store to and retrieves from the shared prefs are integer, string, boolean and List (using JSON to serialize/deserialize list to/from a string). 
Well everything is fine, I can successfully get int, string and boolean from shared prefernces this way, but not the List, in that cas i get a:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

I forgot to tell that the method is declared to return a Object, and when it's called the returned value are typecast to the correct type.
Anyway I don't understand why it says that cannot cast string, it doesn't even return a string? And is this a proper way to do this, I mean is it fully correct to return an object and then cast it.

Full method for getting shared preferences below. Thanks for any advice!

```
public Object getPrefs(String sharedPreferences, String key, int type,
        Context context, Object defaultObject) {
    // A String indicating an error occurred while retrieving shared
    // preferences
    final String ERROR = "ERROR";

    // Set shared preferences from context
    sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferences,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    switch (type) {
    case (0): // <-- Integer
        // Check that defaultObject is of correct instance else collect
        // "hardcoded" default value of 0
        if (defaultObject instanceof Integer) {
            this.logger.logCatTxt(
                    this.logger.getINFO(),
                    this.LOG_TAG + ":getPrefs()",
                    "Integer with value"
                            + Integer.toString(sharedPref.getInt(key,
                                    (Integer) defaultObject))
                            + " retrieved from shared preferences: "
                            + sharedPreferences + ", with key: " + key
                            + ", type: " + Integer.toString(type)
                            + ", context: " + context.toString()
                            + " and default value: "
                            + Integer.toString((Integer) defaultObject));
            return sharedPref.getInt(key, (Integer) defaultObject);
        } else {
            this.logger
                    .logCatTxt(
                            this.logger.getERROR(),
                            this.LOG_TAG + ":getPrefs()",
                            "Default value couldn't be set because of instance mismatch, hardcoded default value of 0 is used. However Integer with value"
                                    + Integer.toString(sharedPref.getInt(
                                            key, 0))
                                    + " retrieved from shared preferences: "
                                    + sharedPreferences
                                    + ", with key: "
                                    + key
                                    + ", type: "
                                    + Integer.toString(type)
                                    + ", context: "
                                    + context.toString()
                                    + " and default value: "
                                    + Integer
                                            .toString((Integer) defaultObject));
            return sharedPref.getInt(key, 0);
        }
    case (1): // <-- String
        // Check that defaultObject is of correct instance else collect
        // "hardcoded" default value of ""
        if (defaultObject instanceof String) {
            this.logger.logCatTxt(
                    this.logger.getINFO(),
                    this.LOG_TAG + ":getPrefs()",
                    "String with value"
                            + sharedPref.getString(key,
                                    (String) defaultObject)
                            + " retrieved from shared preferences: "
                            + sharedPreferences + ", with key: " + key
                            + ", type: " + Integer.toString(type)
                            + " and context: " + context.toString()
                            + " and default value: "
                            + (String) defaultObject);
            return sharedPref.getString(key, (String) defaultObject);
        } else {
            this.logger
                    .logCatTxt(
                            this.logger.getERROR(),
                            this.LOG_TAG + ":getPrefs()",
                            "Default value couldn't be set because of instance mismatch, hardcoded default value of \"\" is used. However String with value"
                                    + sharedPref.getString(key, "")
                                    + " retrieved from shared preferences: "
                                    + sharedPreferences
                                    + ", with key: "
                                    + key
                                    + ", type: "
                                    + Integer.toString(type)
                                    + " and context: " + context.toString());
            return sharedPref.getString(key, "");
        }
    case (2): // <-- Boolean
        // Check that defaultObject is of correct instance else collect
        // "hardcoded" default value of false
        if (defaultObject instanceof Boolean) {
            this.logger.logCatTxt(
                    this.logger.getINFO(),
                    this.LOG_TAG + ":getPrefs()",
                    "Boolean with value"
                            + sharedPref.getBoolean(key,
                                    (Boolean) defaultObject)
                            + " retrieved from shared preferences: "
                            + sharedPreferences + ", with key: " + key
                            + ", type: " + Integer.toString(type)
                            + " and context: " + context.toString()
                            + " and default value: "
                            + (Boolean) defaultObject);
            return sharedPref.getBoolean(key, (Boolean) defaultObject);
        } else {
            this.logger
                    .logCatTxt(
                            this.logger.getERROR(),
                            this.LOG_TAG + ":getPrefs()",
                            "Default value couldn't be set because of instance mismatch, hardcoded default value of false is used. However Boolean with value"
                                    + sharedPref.getBoolean(key, false)
                                    + " retrieved from shared preferences: "
                                    + sharedPreferences
                                    + ", with key: "
                                    + key
                                    + ", type: "
                                    + Integer.toString(type)
                                    + " and context: " + context.toString());
            return sharedPref.getBoolean(key, false);
        }
    case (3): // <-- List
        // Retrieve secondaryListenNumbers to json string and clear
        // secondaryListenNumbers List just to be sure that it's empty
        String json = sharedPref.getString(key, "");
        // List of Strings containing
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // If json string is not empty
        if (json != "") {
            try {
                // Create a JSONArray from json string and retrieve strings
                // from it and and them to secondaryListenNumbers List
                JSONArray a = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                    String secondaryListenNumber = a.optString(i);
                    list.add(secondaryListenNumber);
                }
                this.logger.logCatTxt(this.logger.getINFO(), this.LOG_TAG
                        + ":getPrefs()", "List<String> with value(s)" + json
                        + "   retrieved from shared preferences: "
                        + sharedPreferences + ", with key: " + key
                        + ", type: " + Integer.toString(type)
                        + " and context: " + context.toString());
                // Return the list
                return list;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                this.logger.logCatTxt(this.logger.getERROR(), this.LOG_TAG
                        + ":getPrefs()",
                        "Failed to retrieve List<String> from shared preferences: "
                                + sharedPreferences + ", with key: " + key
                                + ", type: " + Integer.toString(type)
                                + " and context: " + context.toString(), e);
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        this.logger.logCatTxt(this.logger.getWARN(), this.LOG_TAG
                + ":getPrefs()",
                "Unsupported data type was givien as parameter. Shared preferences: "
                        + sharedPreferences + ", with key: " + key
                        + ", type: " + Integer.toString(type)
                        + " and context: " + context.toString());
    }

    // We should never reach this far but if we do an error has occurred and
    // we return the ERROR string
    return ERROR;
}
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. The error happens because you are trying to assign a `String` to a `List`.

Comment: Sorry for that. Sometimes it's to little and some to much code. Well from the error it's not that hard to figure out why the error occurres, the problem was that I didn't find out where the string came from...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your method can return a `String`:

```
return ERROR;
```

which is declared as a `String`.

```
final String ERROR = "ERROR";
```

Also, this presumably returns a `String`:

```
return sharedPref.getString(key, (String) defaultObject);
```

Possibly related:

```
if (json != "") {
```

Don't compare string values with `==` or `!=`.   Use `String#equals`, i.e.

```
if (!json.equals("")) {
```

or even this:

```
if (json.isEmpty()) {
```

It's not a good design in Java to return an error `String` if there is an error.

It would be better to have throw some kind of `Exception` if there is an error, and have the calling method catch the exception and handle the error.

Comment: I feel fairly stupid right now for not catching this earlier... I will refactor the metod to throw an exception if there's an error and not a String.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string with not equal operator: `if (json != "")` You should use `if (!"".equals(json))`.

If json is empty, you return ERROR witch is a String. And cause the exception if you try to cast to a List.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

The error string said: You are trying to cast a String to a List.
Using debugger to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If return type is `Object`, it's a good idea to use `instanseof` when casting to another type. Also as was mentioned before, do not return error strings, better throw an `Exception`